# Can Ansible automatically check state of node and bring it back to desired state if it has become misaligned?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

In Puppet, a node agent will check in with the Master every so often and send facts about the node. The Master will then check these facts are what it should be and if they have become misaligned will revert them to the desired state.

For instance, say I want to be sure that no additional users have been created, any unwarranted users will be deleted.

How can Ansible achieve this given there is no agent? How can it gather facts remotely?

Answer (score 0):

ansible gather facts (and do all actions) by connecting in SSH.

But it also supports a "pull mode" when the nodes check a central configuration: https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull

So I can imagine that you can achieve this by running ansible-pull with a cron.